# Customized route is not working in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular project, I am using a component to create a list of anchors and, I created a component to go to different JSON objects by different URLs when clicking each anchor. I need to create two types of links as "myapp/category" and "myapp/category/sub-category"

This is the code

**list.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
          <dl *ngFor="let post of _postsArray">
            <dt *ngIf="post.parent_id=='0';then m"></dt>
            <ng-template #m><dt><a routerLink="{{post.name}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{post.name}}</a></dt>
                <dl *ngFor="let sub of _postsArray">
                <dt *ngIf="sub.parent_id==post.id;then s"></dt>
                <ng-template #s><dd><a routerLink="{{post.name}}/{{sub.name}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{sub.name}}</a></dd></ng-template>
                </dl>
            </ng-template>
          </dl>
   </div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'explore-all-item', component: AllItemsComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchResultComponent },
  { path: ':post.name', component: FilterComponent },
  { path: ':post.name/sub.name', component: FilterSubComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/explore-all-item', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ];
```

**filter.component.ts:**

```
  cat;
  temp;

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  this.route.params.subscribe((params:any) => {this.temp = 'http://myapp/'+params["post.name"]; this.ngOnInit()})

  }
```

**filter-sub.component.ts:**

```
    cat;
    temp;

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params:any) => {this.temp = 'http://myapp/'+params["post.name"]+'/'+params[sub.name]; this.ngOnInit()})
   }
```

The filter component is for post.name route, so I can setup the url as a category format like - "myapp/post.name" and that is working correctly. 
And the filter-sub component is for post.name/sub.name route, so I can setup the url as a category/sub-category format like - "myapp/post.name/sub.name" and this is not working. Console says "Can not match any routes".
How I can manage this?

Comment: You declared sub.name as constant in your route. Please change it to variable to achieve it

Comment: Yes that solved the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if routes have a common path, they should be children of one another. Next, you forgot a `:` in your route, meaning you could only access `xxx/xxx/sub.name`.

```
{ path: ':post.name', component: FilterComponent, children: [
  { path: ':sub.name', component: FilterSubComponent },
]},
```

Also, if you write routerLinks, you should the input notation, not the interpolation.

```
[routerLink]="[post.name]"
```

Comment: I edited the code, but now the children URL is as "myapp/NaN"

Comment: `+params["post.name"]`. I'm not your colleague and I don't know your project, but I'm pretty sure a name is usually not a number ...